# How does metamask's seed phrase, password and encryptions of private keys works?

Tags: ethereum, metamask

So in metamask there is a password, which I am able to reset by seed phrase, Then how are the private keys, imported by me,  encrypted and stored?
Can you give me a complete workflow?

Answer (score 2):

The password encrypts your data locally. If you import private keys, that information is encrypted with the same local password, but is not associated with your seed phrase. If you lose access to your local MetaMask instance and you restore another from seed phrase, your imported private keys will not be restored with it. You will need to re-import them. The addresses/private keys associated with your seed phrase will always be restored in the same order.